# I want to increase height of this react native curve image

Tags: css, react-native

**I want to increase the height of this image. How can we change the CSS for that? my code also have below image**

[image]

Comment: Try increasing the height and width of the container. Or try to attach html files also.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom component that will handle height and width, and use it.
You can do something like that.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { Image, ImageSourcePropType, ImageStyle, StyleProp } from "react-native";

interface ScaledImageProps {
  source: ImageSourcePropType;
  width?: number;
  height?: number;
  style?: StyleProp<ImageStyle> | undefined;
  onGetHeight?: (height: number) => void
  onGetWidth?: (width: number) => void
}

export const ScaledImage = (props: ScaledImageProps) => {
  const [currentWidth, setCurrentWidth] = useState(0);
  const [currentHeight, setCurrentHeight] = useState(0);

  const setWidth = (width: number) => {
    setCurrentWidth(width)
    if (props.onGetWidth) props.onGetWidth(width)
  }

  const setHeight = (height: number) => {
    setCurrentHeight(height)
    if (props.onGetHeight) props.onGetHeight(height)
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    const uri = Image.resolveAssetSource(props.source).uri

    Image.getSize(uri, (width, height) => {
      if (props.width && !props.height) {
        setWidth(props.width);
        setHeight(height * (props.width / width));
      } else if (!props.width && props.height) {
        setWidth(width * (props.height / height));
        setHeight(props.height);
      } else {
        setWidth(width);
        setHeight(height);
      }
    });
  }, []);

  return (
    <Image
      source={props.source}
      style={[props.style ,{ height: currentHeight, width: currentWidth, }]}
    />
  );
};
```

and if you want to use it, just call it like the following

```
<ScaledImage width={100} source={YourImage} />
```